# Return an array which contains number of elements in an array that is lesser or equal to elements in a given array

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap, complexity-theory, binary-search

I came across this problem and wondering if there could be a better complexity to solve the problem.

For e.g.

- array a = [1,4,2,4]
- array b = [3,5]

**DESIRED OUTPUT** ==> [2, 4]

**EDIT: Put another example**

- array a = [1,4,2,4]
- array b = [3, 1000000]

**DESIRED OUTPUT** ==> [2,4]

So far, what I've found and tried runs in O(nlogn) + O(blogn) and O(n).

**O(nlogn) + O(blogn)** approach:

```
 int binarysearch(vector<int>arr, int l, int r, int target) 
 {
      int mid;
      while(l <= r)
      {
          mid = (r+l) / 2;

          if(arr[mid] > target)
              r = mid - 1;
          else
              l = mid + 1;
      }

      return r; 
 }

vector<int> counts(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    vector<int> result;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // O(nlogn)

    for(auto i : b){
        int count = binarysearch(a, 0, a.size()-1, b); // b*O(log n) times
        result.push_back(count)
    }
    return result;
}
```

**O(n) approach:**

```
vector<int> counts(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    vector<int> result;
    int maxi = *max_element(b.begin(), b.end()) + 1;
    int mymap[maxi] = {0};

    for(auto i : a) mymap[i]++;

    for(int i = 1; i < maxi; i++){
        mymap[i] = mymap[i] + mymap[i-1];
    }

    for(auto i : b){
        result.push_back(mymap[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better complexity than O(n)??

Comment: unclear for me what should be the output. 1, 2 are less than 3

Comment: The title is misleading. Your example output is not a number, but an array

Comment: @Jarod42 So, there are two elements lesser or equal to 3, which is 1 and 2. And, there are 4 elements which is lesser or equal to 5, which are 1,2,4, and 4.

Comment: You could create a map with size `b.size()` and check `if a[i] <= *std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end())` so you don't have to predefine the size. But except this, I don't know what you want to hear.

Comment: @SubMachine Okay, will change it to a better title.

Comment: Which complexity are you asking about? Space? Time? Both?

Comment: @Evg Time complexity.

Comment: @JulianH yes, that could replace the 1000000 but other than that, are there any better approach?

Comment: You have to examine each array element at least once, you can't do it better that in `O(n)` time.

Comment: Not directly related, but binary search is provided by `std::lower_bound`, and `mymap[i] = mymap[i] + mymap[i-1];` by `std::partial_sum`.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++){` -- This is an out of bounds access on the last iteration when accessing `mymap[i]`.

Comment: This is merely `std::sort`, `std::lower_bound`, and then `std::distance`, unless I'm missing something here.  All the algorithm functions are provided by the standard library -- there is no need to write your own for this problem.

Comment: `for(auto i : a) mymap[i]++;` -- this is `O(n log n)` my friend, and `for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)` is not `O(n)` at all.

Comment: @FalconUA Why would `for(auto i : a) mymap[i]++;` be `O(n log n)`? Bear in mind that  `mymap` is an array. `for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) is not O(n) at all.` To clarify, that loop is `O(1)`.

Comment: @noobyz For your first approach, you could also sort both arrays and run 2 pointers from start of the loop to get the answers. For second approach, you first need to mention the constraints, because what if something goes above `1000000` ? Also, there doesn't seem to be a better approach than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out there's a faster way to compute the map index. For e.g. given a = {1,4,2,4,5,8,80} and b = {3,1000000}. **DESIRED OUTPUT** would be [2,7].

Using my previous approach, I would need to compute mymap[4], mymap[5].. mymap[9999]....mymap[1000000]. And that's why the program crashes and returns running time error.

the way we handle this is to use for(auto& entry:mymap) which gives access to all dictionary/map. Then, we use the upper_bound STL C++ to return the correct map.

```
    vector<int> counts(vector<int> nums, vector<int> maxes){


    vector<int> result;

    map<int,unsigned int> mymap;
    for(auto i : nums) mymap[i]++;

    // doesn't need to run 1000000 times
    int temp = 0;
    for(auto& entry: mymap){
        entry.second = entry.second + temp;
        temp = entry.second;
        //cout << "first : " << entry.first << "second: " << entry.second << endl;
    }

    map<int,unsigned int>::iterator itl;
    for(auto i : maxes){
        itl = --mymap.upper_bound(i); // points to the correct map
        result.push_back(itl->second);
    }

    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Passing the vectors as arguments by value forces them to be unnecessarily copied (unless you move, but that's only possible if you don't need the input later). Better to use a reference. Or even better, pass a pair of iterators so that the function is usable with any container. See JulianH's answer for an example.

Comment: `for(auto i : nums) mymap[i]++;` makes counts belonging to O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

> [I am] wondering if there could be a better complexity to solve the problem.
>
> Time complexity.
>
> O(n) approach:

No, there exists no solution with less than linear time complexity.

That said, you linear solution is incorrect. If the input array contains the value 1000000 or greater, or a negative number, then you access outside the bounds of `mymap` and behaviour is undefined. Furthermore, `i <= 1000000` also accesses `mymap` outside the bound upon the last iteration. Besides, `int[1000000]` is way too big to be a local variable. On some systems, even one such variable could cause the stack to overflow.

Comment: @noobyz That still fails to work if the input contains any negative numbers. Even if that's not a problem, 8 GB (more or less depending on CPU architecture) is too much for a local array, even if you have the RAM to spare.

Comment: forgot to put a note that the input would all be positive.

Comment: Turns out I don't really need to set the bound, look at my newest post that avoids computing a lot of map index.

Comment: @noobyz that is still `INT_MAX` if the input array contains `INT_MAX`. Besides, the example program is ill-formed because the size of the array must be a compile time constant.

Comment: I didn't use INT_MAX. Implemented using map and upper_bound STL. Look at my code https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741532/8318666

Comment: @noobyz Oh, I looked at your edited question, rather than the answer. The answer is O(N log N), but it's probably a good algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way doing this than `O(n)`.

So this is also `O(n)` but with STL style adapted:

```
template <class Iter1, class Iter2>
std::vector<std::size_t> counts(const Iter1 beg_a, const Iter1 end_a, const Iter2 beg_b, const Iter2 end_b)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> result;
    const auto& max = *std::max_element(beg_b, end_b);
    std::vector<std::size_t> mymap(max + 1, 0);
    for (auto iter = beg_a; iter != end_a; iter++)
    {
        if (*iter <= max)
        {
            mymap[*iter]++;
        }
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < mymap.size(); i++)
    {
        mymap[i] = mymap[i] + mymap[i - 1];
    }
    for (auto iter = beg_b; iter != end_b; iter++)
    {
        result.push_back(mymap[*iter]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe your code will break given a = {1,4,2,4,5,8,80}; and b = {3,1000000}; Look at my updated solution. The solution is **NOT** to create map[1000000] and play around with the map::upper_bound STL C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

First let's take better notations: let's call A the number of elements in a, B the number of elements in B, and say elements are M bits values.
Your solution is, as others said, `A log(A)` to construct the map plus `B log(A)` to get the returned values.

Using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie you could get `(A+B) log M` instead, which is faster if `A >> M` (but probably slower in practice for most use cases).